# How do I use a 'Control.Tag' within a different method?

Tags: c#, .net

I am not familiar with using `Control.Tag`. All I know is that it can be assigned to any object but what I don't understand is how do I call it within another method? I'm new to this and I do apologize if the question sounds stupid.

The idea is to create an enemyAI that will move by itself. The problem is that I want the enemy unit to be created through code, not on design. I've seen that I can use `for each control` type of code and use `Control.Tag`, but I can't seem to make it work if I call it within the other form.

My question is: Do I put the custom method `controlloop()` within the form where `InitializeComponent()` is or can it be anywhere else? If it doesn't help, how do I make it work to be publicly available on all methods within a form?

(again, I do apologize that the problem sounds stupid, but I'd like help from someone's experience and learn it as well)

The code below is a custom method for looping through controls.

```cs
// checking controls
private void controlLoop()
{
    // for each assigned control of all controls
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        // find 'picturebox' controls
        if (ctrl is PictureBox)
        {
             // detect which one is which
             switch (ctrl.Tag)
             {
             // if the picturebox is an enemy
             case "Enemy":
                 EnemyAI(ctrl);
                 break;
             
             default:
                 MessageBox.Show("Incorrect control type. Please assign it into controls first.");
                 break;
              }
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is what I'm trying to solve but can't. I tried to use `.left` position location but that's where I don't understand what to put to make the enemy unit move after checking all controls.

```cs
// Move the enemy
private void EnemyAI(Control ctrl)
{
    ctrl.Tag.left += Xvel_enemy;
}
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to delete and repost [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896960/c-using-a-control-tag-on-different-method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic "Object" does not have a left property. The picturebox, however, does.

So, in EnemyAI change:

```
ctrl.Tag.left += Xvel_enemy;
```

To:

```
PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)ctrl.Tag;
pb.Left += Xvel_enemy;
```

And you should be good to go.